# Strange construct that used as tag in boost::spirit::x3

Tags: c++, templates

What is the strange language construct `X< class Y > Y;` in following context?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template< typename T >
std::string const type_info_str()
{
    int status = 0;
    auto realname_(abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), nullptr, nullptr, &status));
    switch (status) {
    case -1: return "Could not allocate memory";
    case -2: return "Invalid name under the C++ ABI mangling rules";
    case -3: return "Invalid argument to demangle";
    }
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (std::is_volatile< T >::value) {
        oss << "volatile ";
    }
    oss << realname_;
    std::free(realname_);
    if (std::is_const< T >::value) {
        oss << " const";
    }
    if (std::is_rvalue_reference< T >::value) {
        oss << " &&";
    } else if (std::is_lvalue_reference< T >::value) {
        oss << " &";
    }
    return oss.str();
}

template< typename T >
struct X { };

int main()
{
    X< class Y > Y;
    std::cout << type_info_str< decltype(Y) >() << std::endl; // X<main::Y>
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What is its purpose and semantics?

Comment: I'd say it checks the compile time behavior of `std::ignore`. What's the context you've got that from?

Comment: I don't even. What is your question?

Comment: My question is about `X< class Y > const Y;`.

Comment: It declares a constant named Y of the type X specialized with an inline declaration of a class (also) named Y.

Comment: @user1233963 So you want to say that this language construct called a "inline class declaration"?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's called like that to be honest but I think it's a suitable name

Comment: Both `Y`s means the same? (in the same line)

Comment: @Dukales: first 'Y' is the name of the class, second one is the name of the constant

Comment: @user1233963 Why is there no conflict?

Comment: There never were any conflicts: `class foo {}; int main(){foo foo();}` or `typedef unsigned long DWORD; int main(){DWORD DWORD = 5; return (int)DWORD;}` It can be inferred from the context what you really meant: the type or the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
X  <class Y> Y 
|  ^^^^^^^^^ |
|      |     |
|      |     |
|      |     ---> name of the variable 
|      |
|      ---> the struct is a template which is instantiated with a type 
|          (in this case, the type is an incomplete class named Y)
|
---> struct declared globally
```

As [**Agent_L**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059969/agent-l) mentioned, there is no conflict between the class name and the variable because *it can be inferred from the context what you really meant: the type or the variable.*

Comment: So in angle brackets we have the forward declaration of a class? Like in `class Y; class X { X(Y*) {;} }; class Y { };`?

Comment: I cannot use an incomplete type in any way other than as a tag (compile-time feature), isn't it?